# How to perform ORC in Google Drive REST API (v3)

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api

I'm using PHP and want to perform ORC (Text Detection) on several pictures using Google Drive REST API (not version 2). As you know, in version 3 there is no `insert` method anymore and I must work with `create` or `copy` to perform ORC.

In this new version ORC is enabled by default so I just set orcLanguage and I think google do ORC on the picture without any problem but my question is this, **How can I get the output of ORC action?**

Here is the code I use:

```
function GetORC($filename){ require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC7/vendor/autoload.php'; $client = new Google_Client(); $client->setClientId('>my.client.id<'); $client->setClientSecret('>my.client.secret<'); $client->setRedirectUri('>http://the.uri.i.use<'); $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));

session_start();

if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['accesslic_html/tttest/index.php_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle(uniqid().'.jpg');
    $file->setDescription('A test document');
    $file->setMimeType('image/jpeg');

    $data = file_get_contents($filename);

    $createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
          'data' => $data,
          'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
          'ocrLanguage' => 'fa',
          'uploadType' => 'multipart'
        ));

    var_dump($createdFile);

} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit(); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just to clarify, are you actually referring to Optical Character Recognition (**OCR**) and not **ORC**, like what you have posted?

If it's OCR, sending requests and receiving responses is performed via the HTTP protocol as stated in [Free OCR API](https://www.newocr.com/api/).
In using OCR after uploading pictures, make a GET request to the method's /v1/ocr URI and add the query parameters, for example:

```
GET /v1/ocr?key=api_key&file_id=12345&page=1&lang=eng&psm=3 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.newocr.com
```

If the request succeeds, the server returns the HTTP 200 OK status code along with any metadata:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "status": "success",
  "data":
  {
    "text": "Recognized text",
    "progress": "100"
  }
}
```

You may also check [OCR REST API Developer's Guide](http://www.ocrwebservice.com/api/restguide) for more information and sample codes.